# Android with google app engine (java)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-app-engine

I'm trying to connect my android application to the Google App Engine. I followed [this](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_run_debug.html) google tutorial for a standard example.

My problem is that when I follow the tutorial correctly and I try to execute it, my server doesn't give me back a `hello message`. In debug mode I discovered that my `Async` thread that contacts the server just doesn't execute. Any thoughts?

I get a `Threadpoolexecutor.runworker` popup with source not found.

Comment: can you access the server from another client (firefox or curl)?

Comment: yes, When I run the server and go to the url I'm able to access him. I was also able to link my google account but once I want to ping the server , nothing happens. The standard code that should ping the server is written in a Async method of Android and when I just try to print a toast in this part of the code it doesn't even show this so I think there's something wrong with the threading

Comment: any luck there? having a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I noticed I get the same problem only when I have many of the same thread running concurrently.